# How To Transmit (text/tweet) Temperature and Humidity Data From a Samsung S4

Tags: samsung, sensors

I'd like to be able to use my Samsung S4 as a wireless temperature/humidity for a climate controlled storage unit.  Does anyone know of a way to have that data texted/tweeted from the phone?

Comment: I'd check with some [tag:automation] app. No idea whether there's a dedicated app, and I doubt anything comes preinstalled for that.

Comment: Thanks for the automation suggestion.  For anyone interested in this, I've tried the following apps with no success: "Thermometer & Hygrometer" & "Weather Station"